# how to make the beginning of the url shorter?

Tags: html

I was curious if there would be a way to shorten the beginning of the url. for example I have wlip.net/~name/mysite.com/ How would I be able to get out the wlip.net/~name/ part of the url?

Comment: Are you trying to find something like [TinyURL](http://tinyurl.com/), or save yourself writing full-length/absolute URLs in link `href` attributes, converting *from* `http://www.example.com/directory/page.html` to, for example, `/directory/page.html`?

Comment: Another potential answer would be to write `../mysite.com` if you are referencing from the mysite.com/ subdirectory. But we do need to know what your purpose is!

Answer (score 1):

Register `mysite.com` domain through a registrar, for example [Namecheap](http://www.namecheap.com/). When you have the domain, you will need to configure your web server to use it; we can't tell you that without knowing which web server you're using.

Answer (score 1):

You can visit site http://tinyurl.com/
you can make shorten URL.Like this URL navigate to this page itself http://tinyurl.com/86yrnj4

Answer (score 0):

www.cjb.net

or just google the keywords: "short url"

and you will find lots of sites who could help you with that.